# Add a shape.Textbox to particular location in the excel cell

Tags: c#, vsto

My Excel add-in is build in C#(.net framework 4.0) for office 2010.

I want to add more than 2 Shape.Textbox to an excel cell one after another horizontally.

I'm  using following code:

```
Range rng = UsedArea.Cells[rownum, cellnum];

txtbox = sheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, rng.Left, rng.Top, txt.Width / 2, rng.Height);
```

it adds the textbox to the left of the cell, but how to add another textbox after previous textbox horizontally in the same cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to use first textbox `.left` and `.width` properties when adding second textbox...

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the width of the first textbox to the second textbox position.

sample:

```
        int width = 100;
        int leftpos = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Excel.Shape textbox = shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftpos, 20, width, 20);
            leftpos = leftpos + width;
        }
```